# Paypal crashing?

Tags: html, forms, paypal

So I have built a form where customers can build their own skatebaord by sleceting the colour wheels, trucks etc. I have howerver noticed that some sales seem to not be going through and customers are emailing me that the form keeps crashing.... Any idea why? My code is below.

```
<!-- Start of Add to Cart Form -->
<!-- Note: target="paypal" was replaced with the variable target="_self" -->
<!-- Note: shopping_url also added to code -->
<!-- These two changes allow better functionality with IE and Firefox --> 
 <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_self">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<!-- Replace "business" value with your PayPal Email Address or your Merchant Account ID -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="online@southcoastskates.co.uk">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Personal Built Board 22 Inch">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="29.99">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to after a successful transaction -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.southcoastskates.co.uk">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to after item cancellation -->
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.southcoastskates.co.uk">
<!-- Note: shipping override variable is used with this example -->
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHosted">

<div class="build1">Select 22 inch Board:&#160;&#160;
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="22 Inch Board">
<select name="os1" onchange="diva_imgBySel('theImg',this.selectedIndex)">
<option value="NO COLOUR SELECTED" selected>- CHOOSE COLOUR -</option>
<option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
<option value="LIGHT BLUE">LIGHT BLUE</option>
<option value="DARK BLUE">DARK BLUE</option>
<option value="PINK">PINK</option>
<option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
<option value="RED">RED</option>
<option value="PURPLE">PURPLE</option>
<option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
<option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
<option value="ORANGE">ORANGE</option>
<option value="LIME:">LIME</option>
<option value="GREEN PASTEL:">GREEN PASTEL</option>
<option value="PINK PASTEL:">PINK PASTEL</option>
<option value="DARK GREEN:">DARK GREEN</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="build1">
  Select Truck:&#160;&#160;<br>
  <input type="hidden" name="on6" value="Truck">
  <select name="os6"  onchange="diva_imgBySel2('theImg_truck',this.selectedIndex)">
    <option value="NO TRUCK SELECTED" selected>- CHOOSE TRUCK -</option>
    <option value="ALUMINUM">ALUMINUM</option>
    <option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
    <option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
  </select>
  <p>&nbsp; </p>
</div>


<div class="build1">Front Wheel (Right):&#160;&#160;
<input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Front Wheels (Right)">
<select name="os2" onchange="diva_imgBySel3('theImg_flwheel',this.selectedIndex)">
<option value="NO COLOUR SELECTED" selected>- CHOOSE COLOUR -</option>
<option value="BLUE">BLUE</option>
<option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
<option value="PINK">PINK</option>
<option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
<option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
<option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
<option value="ORANGE">ORANGE</option>
<option value="RED">RED</option>
<option value="PURPLE">PURPLE</option>
<option value="PURPLE TRANS">PURPLE TRANS</option>
<option value="CLEAR BLACK">CLEAR BLACK</option>
<option value="CLEAR WHITE">CLEAR WHITE</option>
<option value="PASTEL PINK">PASTEL PINK</option>
<option value="PASTEL GREEN">PASTEL GREEN</option>
<option value="PASTEL YELLOW">PASTEL YELLOW</option>
<option value="SLATE">SLATE</option>
<option value="GREEN GREY">GREEN GREY</option>
</select></div>

<div class="build1">Front Wheel (Left):&#160;&#160;
<input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Front Wheels (Left)">
<select name="os3"  onchange="diva_imgBySel5('theImg_blwheel',this.selectedIndex)">
<option value="NO COLOUR SELECTED" selected>- CHOOSE COLOUR -</option>
<option value="BLUE">BLUE</option>
<option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
<option value="PINK">PINK</option>
<option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
<option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
<option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
<option value="ORANGE">ORANGE</option>
<option value="RED">RED</option>
<option value="PURPLE">PURPLE</option>
<option value="PURPLE TRANS">PURPLE TRANS</option>
<option value="CLEAR BLACK">CLEAR BLACK</option>
<option value="CLEAR WHITE">CLEAR WHITE</option>
<option value="PASTEL PINK">PASTEL PINK</option>
<option value="PASTEL GREEN">PASTEL GREEN</option>
<option value="PASTEL YELLOW">PASTEL YELLOW</option>
<option value="SLATE">SLATE</option>
<option value="GREEN GREY">GREEN GREY</option>
</select></div>

<div class="build1">Back Wheel (Right):&#160;&#160;
<input type="hidden" name="on4" value="Back Wheels (Right)">
<select name="os4"  onchange="diva_imgBySel4('theImg_frwheel',this.selectedIndex)">
<option value="NO COLOUR SELECTED" selected>- CHOOSE COLOUR -</option>
<option value="BLUE">BLUE</option>
<option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
<option value="PINK">PINK</option>
<option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
<option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
<option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
<option value="ORANGE">ORANGE</option>
<option value="RED">RED</option>
<option value="PURPLE">PURPLE</option>
<option value="PURPLE TRANS">PURPLE TRANS</option>
<option value="CLEAR BLACK">CLEAR BLACK</option>
<option value="CLEAR WHITE">CLEAR WHITE</option>
<option value="PASTEL PINK">PASTEL PINK</option>
<option value="PASTEL GREEN">PASTEL GREEN</option>
<option value="PASTEL YELLOW">PASTEL YELLOW</option>
<option value="SLATE">SLATE</option>
<option value="GREEN GREY">GREEN GREY</option>
</select></div>

<div class="build1">Back Wheel (Left):&#160;&#160;
<input type="hidden" name="on5" value="Back Wheels (Left)">
<select name="os5" onchange="diva_imgBySel6('theImg_brwheel',this.selectedIndex)">
<option value="NO COLOUR SELECTED">- CHOOSE COLOUR -</option>
<option value="BLUE">BLUE</option>
<option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
<option value="PINK">PINK</option>
<option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
<option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
<option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
<option value="ORANGE">ORANGE</option>
<option value="RED">RED</option>
<option value="PURPLE">PURPLE</option>
<option value="PURPLE TRANS">PURPLE TRANS</option>
<option value="CLEAR BLACK">CLEAR BLACK</option>
<option value="CLEAR WHITE">CLEAR WHITE</option>
<option value="PASTEL PINK">PASTEL PINK</option>
<option value="PASTEL GREEN">PASTEL GREEN</option>
<option value="PASTEL YELLOW">PASTEL YELLOW</option>
<option value="SLATE">SLATE</option>
<option value="GREEN GREY">GREEN GREY</option>
</select></div>

<div class="build1">
  <p>&nbsp; </p>
  Select abec:&#160;&#160;
  <input type="hidden" name="on7" value="abec">
  <select name="os7">
    <option value="7" selected>7</option>
   <!-- <option value="9">9</option>-->
      </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="7">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="29.99">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="9">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="47.99">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
   <p style="font-size:12px"> abec9 extra charge &pound;8.00</p>
</div>

<div class="build1">  <p>&nbsp; </p>
Delivery outside UK?&#160;&#160;
    <select name="shipping" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
      <option selected value="0.00">NO</option>
      <option value="6.50">YES</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  <p style="font-size:12px; padding-bottom:3em;"> £6.50 5 day service</p>
</div>

<div class="build5">
<input type="image"  src="images/add.png" border="0" name="submit" width="87" height="23" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!"></td>

<!--  Start of View Cart Button Code  -->
<form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<!-- If using a Business or Company Logo Graphic, include the "cpp_header_image" variable in your View Cart code. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="http://southcoastskates.co.uk/images/logo.png"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="display" value="1">
<!-- Replace "business" value with your PayPal Email Address or Account ID -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="online@southcoastskates.co.uk">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to -->
<input type="image" src="images/view.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="images/view.png" width="1" height="1">
</form> 
<!--  End of View Cart Button Code  -->
```

Comment: what kind of error message are they seeing that describe "paypal crashing"?

Comment: Most customer as saying things along these lines : Id like to use your Black Friday offer for the 22" skateboard (£29.99) but after trying many times still cannot pass paypal. It seems to be an IT error.

Comment: I have tried and it seems to work fine? However id say 1/5 sales seems to be failing?

Comment: If it is working fine for most of the sales, if there is some failure, it could probably due to buyer's account funding source issue which unable to make payment. To confirm this, we need to see what error message are they seeing in PayPal checkout page.